# laravel Can't update database and get error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, error-handling, sql-update

I using laravel framework make method and function for update row in database, but found error **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** and i try to handle it, but still can't
here in form **edit.blade.php** :

```
        {{ Form::model($datas, array('route' => array('barang.update' , $datas->id) , 'method'=> 'PATCH') )}}
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('Nama Barang', 'Nama Barang :') }}
            {{ Form::text('nama_barang',null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ Form::label('Harga Barang', 'Harga Barang :') }}
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Rp</span>
                {{ Form::text('harga_barang',null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
                <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              {{ Form::label('Jumlah Barang', 'Jumlah Barang :') }}
              <div class="input-group">
                {{ Form::text('jumlah',null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
                <span class="input-group-addon">Item</span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputFile">Foto Barang</label>
              <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">

              <!-- <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p> -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer">
            {{ Form::submit('Simpan', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Simpan dan Publikasi</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Batal</button>
          </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

here in Controller **BarangContr.php** :

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $datas = BarangModel::find($id);
        return View::make('admin/barang/edit', compact('datas'));
    }

    public function update($id)
    {

        $datas = new BarangModel;
        $datas -> nama_barang  = Input::get('nama_barang');
        $datas -> harga_barang = Input::get('harga_barang');
        $datas -> jumlah       = Input::get('jumlah');
       $barang = BarangModel::find($id);
       $barang->update($datas);

       return $this->index();
    }
```

here in route code **route.php** :

```
Route::resource('barang', 'BarangContr');
Route::get('/barang/edit/{id}', 'BarangContr@edit');
Route::post('/barang/update/{id}', array('as' => 'barang.update' , 'uses' => 'BarangContr@update'));
```

here in BarangModel.php code :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BarangModel extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'tb_barang';
    protected $primarykey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['kode_barang', 'nama_barang', 'harga_barang', 'jumlah'];
}
```

Thanks before for your answer :)

Comment: change your Route::post('/barang/update/{id}' to Route::patch('/bara...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using patch i would suggest to change your route to the following

```
Route::post('/barang/update/{id}', array('as' => 'barang.update' , 'uses' => 'BarangContr@update'));
```

to

```
Route::patch('/barang/update/{id}', array('as' => 'barang.update' , 'uses' => 'BarangContr@update'));
```

Also you should change your controller to the following:

```
    $datas = BarangModel::find($id);
    $datas->nama_barang  = Input::get('nama_barang');
    $datas->harga_barang = Input::get('harga_barang');
    $datas->jumlah       = Input::get('jumlah');
    $datas->save();

   return $this->index();
```

Comment: thanks, already completed, it must include same 'patch' method in the route and form, thanks again before

Answer (score 0):

You have put `method="PATCH"` in your form while your route is for method `POST`. HTML5 forms only accept `GET` or `POST` methods. Please try again by removing the method attribute (so it returns to `POST` default).

By the way, Laravel can use other route methods by using hidden inputs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#form-method-spoofing